# rails3 haml error logging no longer very descriptive

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, haml

Since migrating a project to rails 3, haml errors are not very descriptive..

All we're getting in the logs is a generic nil object error.

For instance in rails 2.3.8 when the indentation in a haml file was incorrect we'd get an error message pointing to the file and approx line.

However now in rails 3 we just get

NoMethodError (You have a nil object when you didn't expect it!
You might have expected an instance of Array.
The error occurred while evaluating nil.+):

Using ruby 1.9.2 / rails 3 / haml 3.0.18

Thanks for your help

Dom

Comment: NoMethodError is Ruby not haml.

Comment: looks like this is the case for all errors, not just haml ones. is there something needed to get a more verbose message outputted to the log.